# Are there any nosql database could do search(like lucene) on map/reduce

Tags: database, mapreduce, lucene, document-oriented-db

I'm using cloudant which I could use mapreduce to project view of data and also it could search document with lucene

But these 2 feature is separate and cannot be used together

Suppose I make a game with userdata like this

```
{
    name: ""
    items:[]        
}
```

Each user has item. Then I want to let user find all swords with quality +10. With cloudant I might project type and quality as key and use query `key=["sword",10]`

But it cannot make query more complex than that like lucene could do. To do lucene I need to normalize all items to be document and reference it with owner

I really wish I could do a lucene search on a key of data projection. I mean, instead of normalization, I could store nested document as I want and use map/reduce to project data inside document so I could search for items directly

PS. If that database has partial update by scripting and inherently has transaction update feature that would be the best

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd suggest trying out [elasticsearch](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/index.html).

Seems like your use case should be covered by the [search api](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search.html)

If you need to do more complex analytics elasticsearch supports [aggregations](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations.html).

Comment: It seem there are nested object feature related to what I would like to have. I will take a look at it. thanks

Comment: very useful indeed! I will check if it makes sense to move to elasticsearch instead of riak for my application, too.

Answer (score 2):

I am not at all sure that I got the question correctly, but you may want to take a look at [riak](http://basho.com/products/). It offers a solr-based search, which is quite [well documented](http://docs.basho.com/riak/kv/2.2.0/developing/usage/search). I have used it in the past for distributed search over a distributed key-value index and it was quite fast.

If you use this, you will also need to take a look at the [syntax of solr queries](http://www.solrtutorial.com/solr-query-syntax.html), so I add it here to save you some time. However, keep in mind that not all of those solr query functionalities were available in riak (at least that was when I used it).

Answer (score 1):

There are several solutions that would do the job. I can give my 2 cents proposing the well established MongoDB. With MongoDB you can create a text-Index on a given field and then do a full text Search as explained [here](https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/full-text-search-in-mongodb--cms-24835). The feature is in MongoDb since version 2.4 and the syntax is well documented on MongoDB docs.

Comment: Well, if I remember it right. Mongo could only do full text search to search only document, same as couchdb. I want to find things better than couchdb